# How can I select specific strings and some with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that will scan through web pages looking for email addresses with a specific domain. In this example, we will use @xyz.com as the domain.

In my content script `script.js`and hard coded HMTL page `index.html` I have the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('body:contains("@xyz.com")').css("text-decoration", "underline");

});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>my page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="text-container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, tenetur natus doloremque laborum quos iste ipsum rerum obcaecati impedit odit illo dolorum ab tempora nihil dicta earum fugiat. Temporibus, voluptatibus. Lorem ipsum JohnJones.@xyz.com
        , consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, doloribus, dolorem iusto blanditiis unde eius illum consequuntur neque dicta incidunt ullam ea hic porro optio ratione repellat perspiciatis. Enim, iure! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Error, nostrum, aliquid, animi, ut quas placeat totam sunt tempora commodi nihil ullam alias modi dicta saepe minima ab quo voluptatem obcaecati? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, dolor quis. Sunt, ut, explicabo,
        aliquam SarahBrown.@xyz.com tempore quidem voluptates cupiditate voluptas illo saepe quaerat numquam recusandae? Qui, necessitatibus, est!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to select only the email addresses but this clearly doesn't work since it selects everything.

How can I select text matching my keyword (domain) and then further select characters to the left of it to capture the name until it hits a space or an illegal character an email address couldn't use?

This is problematic because this Extension will run on different pages so it's impossible to tell what element text will be nested in for 100% success rate.

Comment: Plain text email in your example is part of other plain text and doesn't have a separate node that can be "selected". Instead you'll have to create a new node and insert it in place of the email text. This is usually called "linkifying" (see [some answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+linkify+email) on that), I believe there must be an exact duplicate on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Regex is confusing at first but it is the best option for something like this. 
Here is the regex I use for detecting emails

[[\w|._%+-]*@xyz.com](https://regex101.com/r/oR7oJ8/2)

To break it down, "\w" matches any word character. "|" means "or" and "._%+-" are other characters that could be used in an email. "*" after brackets means any number of characters that match the contents of the brackets. The rest is exactly what it looks like.

Regex code is designated by putting a "/" before and after the code and the "g" at the end tells it to match multiple values.

You can find out more about how the replace command works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

See a working example using your code below:

```js
var emailPattern = new RegExp(/[\w|._%+-]*@xyz.com/g);
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(emailPattern, "<u>$&</u>");
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0-alpha1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>my page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="text-container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, tenetur natus doloremque laborum quos iste ipsum rerum obcaecati impedit odit illo dolorum ab tempora nihil dicta earum fugiat. Temporibus, voluptatibus. Lorem ipsum JohnJones.@xyz.com
        , consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, doloribus, dolorem iusto blanditiis unde eius illum consequuntur neque dicta incidunt ullam ea hic porro optio ratione repellat perspiciatis. Enim, iure! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Error, nostrum, aliquid, animi, ut quas placeat totam sunt tempora commodi nihil ullam alias modi dicta saepe minima ab quo voluptatem obcaecati? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, dolor quis. Sunt, ut, explicabo,
        aliquam SarahBrown.@xyz.com tempore quidem voluptates cupiditate voluptas illo saepe quaerat numquam recusandae? Qui, necessitatibus, est!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need to match other domain's emails you can use this Regex instead:

[[\w|.*%+-]*@\w*.[\w|.*%+-]*\b](https://regex101.com/r/oR7oJ8/1)